# Totals instead of Count in this query

Tags: sql, sum

I have a working query that individuals helped me get working. It gives me the total number of orders in 0-30 days, 31-60, etc. I've now been asked to replace the number with the total amount of those orders. I'm not certain of the syntax for the SUM lines. I'm not 100% sure that I can total the orders using this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

bh.Customer_Name AS Customer_Name,
ad.Email_Address,
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '0 - 30' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0_30",
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '31 - 60' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "31_60",
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '61 - 90' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "61_90",
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '90+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "90+"

FROM

dbo.Billing_Detail bd LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Billing_Header bh ON bd.Billing_Header_ID = bh.Billing_Header_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Commission_Distribution cd ON bh.Billing_Header_ID = cd.Billing_Header_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Salesman_Code sc ON cd.Salesman_Code = sc.Salesman_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Address ad ON bh.Billing_Header_ID = ad.Billing_Header_ID 

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ((DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),bh.Invoice_Date)*-1) <= '30') 
    THEN '0 - 30'
    WHEN '30' < (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),bh.Invoice_Date)*-1) AND (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),bh.Invoice_Date)*-1) <= '60'
    THEN '31 - 60'
   WHEN '61' < (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),bh.Invoice_Date)*-1) AND (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),bh.Invoice_Date)*-1) <= '90'
    THEN '61 - 90'    
  ELSE '90+'
    END AS Time
 ) AS CA1 

WHERE
bd.Product_Code  NOT LIKE  '%PROCESS%' AND
bd.Product_Code  NOT LIKE  '%DEPOSIT%' AND
DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),bh.Invoice_Date)  <=  -30 AND
bh.Balance_Due  >  '0' AND
bd.Company_Code  =  'AIN' AND
bh.Invoice_Number  NOT LIKE  '%-%' AND
bd.Unit_Price  >  '0' AND
ad.Address_Type  IN  ( '' , 'BILLING' ) 

GROUP by bh.Customer_Name, ad.Email_Address
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside each of your sums, you have a case statement which gives you 1 if a line satisfies a condition (i.e., if it corresponds to an order within a desired time frame) and 0 otherwise. The sum of all the 1's is the number of lines (orders) that satisfy the condition. Now, instead of adding 1 for each line that satisfies the condition (which amounts to counting the lines in question), you want to add its respective amount (which amounts to calculating the total amount for the lines in question). So you can use the same code, just replace the sums with these:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '0 - 30' THEN CA1.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS "0_30",
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '31 - 60' THEN CA1.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS "31_60",
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '61 - 90' THEN CA1.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS "61_90",
SUM(CASE WHEN CA1.Time = '90+' THEN CA1.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS "90+"
```

Comment: Downernn, Thank you so much for the help, and the explanation. That really helps, I can now take this and see if I can use it somewhere else, now that I understand what it's doing. Thanks again.